# Simple geometric proof for Snell's law of refraction

Tags: calculus, geometry

Snell's law of refraction can be derived from Fermat's principle
that light travels paths that minimize the time using simple
calculus. Since Snell's law only involves sines I wonder whether
this minimum problem has a simple geometric solution.

Comment: This is treated in "What Is Mathematics" by Courant and Robbins. See the bottom half of [this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=_kYBqLc5QoQC&lpg=PA330&vq=heron&pg=PA330#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @Michael really? I don't have a copy at hand right now, but from the title of the section I would be more inclined to think that the geometric construction relates to _Heron's principle_, which is the principle of reflection that incidence angle is the same as the reflection angle, and which indeed has a simple geometric proof. I would be very pleasantly surprised if there is in Courant and Robbins a geometric proof of Snell's law of refraction.

Comment: Huygen's gave a somewhat geometric proof of Snell's law, however, he did not start with Fermat's principle, but rather the assumption that light is a wave, that wave speed equals the product of wave length and frequency, that frequency is invariant across a boundary, and a continuity criterion. I suppose, however, that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @WillieWong Ah you're right - I read the OP's question too quickly. They mention Snell's law at the end of that section, but don't derive it geometrically.

Comment: There is a very detailed proof, using Ptolemy's Theorem, in Ivan Niven's bwautiful book *Maxima and Minima Without Calculus.*

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps this will help, if you are looking at a non Calculus approach.[image]
Consider two parallel rays $A$ and $B$ coming through the medium $1$ (say air) to the medium $2$ (say water). Upon arrival at the interface $\mathcal{L}$ between the two media (air and water), they continue their parallel course in the directions $U$ and $V$ respectively.

Let us assume that at time $t=0$, light ray $A$ arrives at the interface $\mathcal{L}$ at point $C$, while ray $B$ is still shy of the surface by a distance $PD$.  $B$ travels at the speed $v_{1}=\frac{c}{n_{1}}$ and arrives at $D$ in $t$ seconds. During this time interval, ray $A$ continues its journey through the medium $2$ at a speed $v_{2}=\frac{c}{n_{2}}$ and reaches the point $Q$.

We can formulate the rest, geometrically (looking at the parallel lines) from the figure. Let $x$ denote the distance between $C$ and $D$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
x \sin\left(\theta_{i}\right) &=& PD \\
&=& v_{1} t \\
&=& \frac{c}{n_{1}} t  \\
x \sin\left(\theta_{r}\right) &=& CQ \\
&=& v_{2} t \\
&=& \frac{c}{n_{2}} t 
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus,

\begin{eqnarray*}
n_{1} \sin\left(\theta_{i}\right) &=& \frac{c}{x} t  \\
n_{2} \sin\left(\theta_{r}\right) &=& \frac{c}{x} t 
\end{eqnarray*}

Re arranging this will take us to the Snell's law as we know.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{n_{2} }{n_{1}} &=& \frac{\sin\left(\theta_{i}\right) }{ \sin\left(\theta_{r}\right)}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This is far simpler than the use of Fermat principle. +1

Comment: This proof is flawed - it's not shown that $CP$ and $DQ$ are perpendicular to the lines of travel they meet. This is required to use e.g. $x \sin\left(\theta_{i}\right)$ for $PD$. You can assume that one of them is perpendicular by starting the light rays with an appropriate delay, but that leaves the other. 

Note that the proof doesn't make use of the minimality of the travel time. Something like that minimality would have to be used to show that, given that $CP$ is perpendicular to $BD$, $DQ$ must be perpendicular to $CU$, if the proof could be mended, although I'm not sure it can.

Answer (score 9):

Let upper half plane be a medium with refractive index $n_1$and the lower half plane be another medium with refractive index $n_2$. Let $(a_1,b_1)$and $(a_2,b_2)$ be the starting point and end point of light traveled, while $(x,0)$ is the point of refraction.

Time of light traveled $$t=\frac {n_1}c\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+b_1^2}+\frac {n_2}c\sqrt{(a_2-x)^2+b_2^2}$$
where $c$ is the speed of light

By Fermat's principle, we need to minimize $t$
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=0$$$$\frac {n_1}c \frac {x-a_1}{\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+b_1^2}}+\frac {n_2}c \frac {-x+a_2}{\sqrt{(a_2-x)^2+b_2^2}}=0$$$$n_1\frac {x-a_1}{\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+b_1^2}}=n_2\frac {x-a_2}{\sqrt{(a_2-x)^2+b_2^2}}$$
note that $\frac {x-a_1}{\sqrt{(x-a_1)^2+b_1^2}}=\sin\theta_1$ and $\frac {x-a_2}{\sqrt{(a_2-x)^2+b_2^2}}=\sin\theta_2$,
proved.

Comment: This is not a purely geometric solution. This is the solution that the poster explicitly requested something different from.