# proving Snell's law using derivatives

Tags: derivatives

While proving Snell's law with calculus, we come to statements similar to [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153775/simple-proof-for-snells-law-of-refraction).

Now, we finally resolve to:
$$\frac {dt}{dx}\ =\frac{sinθ_1}{c1}-\frac {sinθ_2}{c_2}$$

Now, since the domain is restricted to $0$ to $d$ inclusive, and it is said that there is a point $x_o$ belonging to $[0, d]$, where
$$\frac{dt}{dx}\ =\ 0$$  and that $dt/dx$ on $x$ is $<0$ and on $d$ is $>0$
*and*, that there is only one such point because $t$ is an *increasing* function of $x$.

Now, the biggest question is:
1) since time is always an increasing function, it's monotonic, hence, how is there one point where the derivative is zero?
        The only point I could think of would be $0$ where only the right hand derivative is zero, but then $$ \frac{dt}{dx}\ $$ would not exist.

Where am I misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 2):

When you say “time is always an increasing function,” I think you're assuming that time is an *independent* variable.  And this is usually the case in when studying quantities that change “over time.”  When a particle moves in space, its position is a function of time, and time is independent.

However, in this context, “time” is shorthand for the travel time—the amount of time the light requires to travel from one point to another. It is a *dependent* variable, depending on the path chosen.  Some paths will result in a shorter travel time than others.  We are looking for the path which minimizes the travel time.

The reason we are able to think of this as a single-variable calculus problem is that we can represent the path taken by a single point, the point $x$ of refraction.  Everything else is determined by this.  Thus time is a function of a single variable $x$.

Comment: then why is t(x) said to be an increasing function?

Comment: and why is there only one point?

Comment: where the derivative is zero?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal: I don't think it comes from first principles that $t(x)$ should have a single point where the derivative is zero.  That comes from the formula for $t(x)$.  And $t(x)$ is not an increasing function in general, but it is on any interval where its derivative is positive.

Comment: how would t(x) even have the derivatives at the end points even when the domain is constrained to [0, 4]?

Comment: and like you have mentioned above, if the derivative is increasing on an open interval belonging to [0, 4], it wouldn't even have a single derivative in that interval.

Comment: so the condition would never satisfy?

Comment: Re the question three comments above from this one: It isn't necessary that there be a derivative at the end points.  We simply compare the values of the function at the endpoints with the values at the critical points to find the maximum.  It could be the maximum occurs on the endpoint.  In this case, it is possible to show that it does not.

Comment: The question three comments above from **this** comment doesn't make sense to me.  From the formula for $t(x)$, we can show that $dt/dx$ is positive on some open subinterval of $[0,4]$.  Hence $t$ is increasing on that interval.

Comment: Thomas' calculus explicitly says that at x = 0 the derivative is -ve and at x = 4 the derivative is positive, it must imply that in this general phenomena, this is _always_ the case.  But, how you've answered is quite contradicting to what is written in the book.

Comment: @BeshalJaenal OK. At least one of us is confused. You started off with a very specific question but now you've totally lost me. Can you ask another question? It might invite more answers.

Comment: okay, I'll try that.

Comment: Am I to assume that the use of Taylor's Series would go along with this as well? finding snell's law while adding many more variables as a calculus?

Comment: @C.Jordan Snell's law is expressed in terms of trigonometric functions, so I don't think you can use Taylor series to derive it.  If that's doesn't answer your question, you would be better off writing a new question and going into more detail.

Comment: Okay, will do, thank you for your honest answer.